# How do I get YoutubeVideo metadata with C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm trying to search on YouTube with just the video name, get the metadata of the first video (tag, title, maker) and store it in my database. How can I do the same in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [youtube api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet)

[Search by keyword section](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#search_by_keyword):

```
      var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
      {
        ApiKey = "REPLACE_ME",
        ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
      });

      var searchListRequest = youtubeService.Search.List("snippet");
      searchListRequest.Q = "Google"; // Replace with your search term.
      searchListRequest.MaxResults = 50;

      // Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified query term.
      var searchListResponse = await searchListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

      List<string> videos = new List<string>();
      List<string> channels = new List<string>();
      List<string> playlists = new List<string>();

      // Add each result to the appropriate list, and then display the lists of
      // matching videos, channels, and playlists.
      foreach (var searchResult in searchListResponse.Items)
      {
        switch (searchResult.Id.Kind)
        {
          case "youtube#video":
            videos.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.VideoId));
            break;

          case "youtube#channel":
            channels.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.ChannelId));
            break;

          case "youtube#playlist":
            playlists.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.PlaylistId));
            break;
        }
      }

      Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Videos:\n{0}\n", string.Join("\n", videos)));
      Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Channels:\n{0}\n", string.Join("\n", channels)));
      Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Playlists:\n{0}\n", string.Join("\n", playlists)));
```

Comment: +How to get tags?